# How to turn on/off a sub circuit with a transistor

Tags: transistors, pcb, switches

I bought a [dtc144 transistor](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/348/dtc144ee-209254.pdf) because it was written in [its datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/348/dtc144ee-209254.pdf) that it could do a "Switching circuit" ( as it is written in the Applications section in the datasheet). I though it meant that I could turn on/off a sub-circuit in my PCB design, but when I tested, it didn't worked as I imagined.

Did I misunderstand what switching circuit means? How can I use this transistor to turn on/off a sub circuit?

The datasheet (first page) has the following image:

[image: dtc144_inner_circuit]

(if you can not see the image, check the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/348/dtc144ee-209254.pdf). I am having problems to upload the image)

I thought that as a transistor, if I put a GND in the "in" pin, the transistor would behave as high impedance between the "out" and the "gnd" pins, and low inpedance if I put VCC instead of GND in the "in" pin. But it seems that I am wrong.

I'd appreciate if you could help me understand. Thanks.

Comment: I see two problems with the second diagram. Not that they have anything to do with the question...

Comment: OK we hear what you expected, now what did you get?

Comment: I connected 3v3 in "out" pin, in "gnd" pin I connected my circuit and I put 3v3 in "in" pin to close the switch and then I have 1v5 in "gnd" pin instead of 3v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought that as a transistor, if I put a GND in the "in" pin, the
>   transistor would behave as high impedance between the "out" and the
>   "gnd" pins, and low inpedance if I put VCC instead of GND in the "in"
>   pin. But it seems that I am wrong.

No, you are correct, except that you left something out. Your description of how the transistor acts as a switch is right on, *as long as the "gnd" pin is tied to GND*. If you are trying to use the OUT/GND path as a short / open element in a signal path, it won't work. It will only provide a short/open path to ground.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I was trying to put the transistor switch between the power source (+) and the VCC of my circuit and I was having a big drop of voltage (by half). Now I changed the transistor to rely between the gnd of my circuit and the power source (-) and it works (I have a mini drop of 100 mV). I didn't really understand why, but this is another question.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a specific question about a specific circuit, but you're not ready for this yet.  You need to *understand* how a transistor works, at least its first pass approximation.  The type of transistor you show is a NPN, which is a type of bipolar junction transistor (BJT).

Surely there are many basic introductions to NPN transistors out there, so I'm not going to go into any detail.  Basically, you put a little current into the base and out the emitter, and the transistor can support a lot of current into the collector and out the emitter.

Your top circuit is actually correct in that when IN is grounded, the transistor is off, which essentially open-circuits OUT.  When IN is raised to high enough voltage, then current will flow into the base, and the transistor will pull down on OUT.  There are of course a lot of details.  Without knowing exactly what you did, we can't tell why you didn't observe the behavior as described above.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the data sheet the transistor works as a switch if OUT has a higher voltage potential than IN. IN must be 3 volts (value taken from table) or higher than GND for the transistor to conduct from OUT to GND (switch closed). If IN is close to 0 volts compared to GND the transistor is not conducting OUT to GND (switch open).